# Rails Association Design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an Article model which can have exactly one Image model associated with it.  However, my Image model can be associated to many articles.  My first stab at this was to define the relationship via:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :image
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :articles :dependent => :nullify
end
```

This technically works and it only requires the image_id foreign key to be on the articles table.  This makes perfect sense from the database perspective, but it feels wrong.  It doesn't make sense to say an article belongs_to an image.  In reality, an image belongs to an article.  It would make more sense to say that an Article has_one image, but if I use has_one that puts article_id foreign key on the Images table.  Since an Image can have more than one Article, it really doesn't make sense to have a single article_id column defined on the Images table.

There's got to be an easier way to model this.

Comment: Well, it makes sense from a database perspective, so I'd go with that. Might not make perfect sense from a Rails perspective because of the wording, but the relationship is schematically appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :image
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles, :dependent => :nullify
end
```